# tuple(str) returns a tuple element per character

Tags: python, tuples

I have a function that takes in a tuple of datetime formats or a single datetime format Its signature looks like this

```
`datetime_formats: Union[Tuple[str, ...], str] = (ISO_8601_FORMAT, ...) -> None
```

In the `__init__` I have a simple

```
if isinstance(datetime_formats, str)
    datetime_formats = tuple(datetime_formats)
```

Which lead to me discovering that calling `Tuple` on a string splits the string into a Tuple with an element per character in the string

```
>>> tuple('%Ztest')
('%', 'Z', 't', 'e', 's', 't')
```

What can I do to get

```
>>> tuple('%Ztest')
('%Ztest',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either start with a list declaration using brackets

```
>>> tuple(['%Ztest'])
('%Ztest',)
```

Or do a implicit tuple declaration using a comma

```
>>> '%Ztest',
('%Ztest',)
```

If you use a explicit list declaration you'll run into the same splitting behavior

```
>>> tuple(list('%Ztest'))
('%', 'Z', 't', 'e', 's', 't')
```

Comment: terminology nitpick: these are not declarations. python doesn't *have* variable declarations. using square brackets like that is a *list literal*, using parentheses (with the comma) is a *tuple literal*. calling `list` or `tuple` is simply calling a constructor.

Comment: I appreciate that nitpick.